# Sweep command does not show in the wallet properties tab

Tags: armory, sweep

I am using Armory 96.0.  The sweep command does not show in the wallet properties tab.  This is true for both my online WIndows 10 pro and offline windows 8.0

Comment: Hey, this sounds more like a bug report than a question. What do you want to know?

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.stackexchange.com. A self-help question and answer website run by people like you. What exactly is your question? Use that [Edit] link under your question.

Comment: Show screenshot bro! maybe its small problem